# Redirect end folder to same URL without this folder

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect

I'd like to make a 301 redirect from URLs that end in /amp in my site to the same URLs without this last folder. All the question I've seen doesn't work.

The idea is to make a rule so:

https://example.com/directory/name-of-the-article/amp (does not ends with slash)

Redirect to https://example.com/name-of-the-article/ (ends with slash)

- /directory/ can be different in every URL but it will be always just one.

This is my actual htaccess document:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301] 
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Answer (score 0):

### 1. **301 from .htaccess**

I've tested this on my server and work fine:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/amp$ https://yourwebsite.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

---

### 2. **Redirect from HTML**

However, if you want to redirect from AMP page to normal article page, you can use a simple HTML code, for example:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;URL=https://website.com/normal-page/">
```

You can recover the current url by PHP with:

```
$actual_link = (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) ? "https" : "http") . "://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";
```

After you can simply replace */amp* with PHP command:

```
$normal_page = str_replace('/amp', '', $actual_link);
```

For best result, don't use *str_replace* but a good *regex* command

Comment: If I delete the plugin, I don't get the redirect and I lose all my organic traffic. The plugin has been installed for 2 months.
The meta refresh is not a 301 redirect.

Answer (score 0):

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /amp$
RewriteRule ^(.+)/(.+)/amp$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$2/ [L,R=301]

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301] 
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: That doesn't work. If I do that there's an error that says that there are too many redirections. It creates a redirection loop.

Comment: can you share another URL which is creating problem?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301] 
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^(.*)\/amp$ $1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```